# Post a large file with ApiGatewayV2 and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a 6Mb file that I want to upload to S3.

Currently, I use this configuration:

serverless.yml:

```
lambdaApi:
  handler: public/index.php
  events:
    - httpApi: '*'

resources:
  Conditions:
  Resources:
    ApiMapping:
      Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping'
      Condition: HaveCustomDomain
      DependsOn: HttpApiIntegrationApi
      Properties:
        ApiMappingKey: "my-project"
        DomainName: my.domain.co
        ApiId: !Ref HttpApi
        Stage: "$default"
```

The problem is that because of my `lambdaApi` Lambda, my POST request cannot exceed 6MB.

I've tried to used this solution (from here: https://theburningmonk.com/2020/04/hit-the-6mb-lambda-payload-limit-heres-what-you-can-do/):

[image]

But it does not work with `AWS ApiGatewayV2`.

When I try the plugin https://github.com/serverless-operations/serverless-apigateway-service-proxy with this custom serverless:

```
  apiGatewayServiceProxies:
    - s3:
        path: /my/path
        method: post
        action: PutObject
        bucket: dev-connect-files
        cors: true
        requestParameters:
          # if requestParameters has a 'integration.request.path.object' property you should remove the key setting
          'integration.request.path.object': 'context.requestId'
          'integration.request.header.cache-control': "'public, max-age=31536000, immutable'"
```

I can create a POST route but it is detached from my real API.

I can't access the PHP code that the `/my/path` is supposed to execute.

I know I have the option of using a pre-signed URL but I don't want to use it for the moment.

Question:

1. Is it possible to use this plugin
   https://github.com/serverless-operations/serverless-apigateway-service-proxy
   with `AWS ApiGatewayV2`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not really an answer, but why pay for APIGateway, put operations on  S3, etc, when you can use presigned URLs to upload large files and avoid timeouts, upload limits, and reduce costs

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html

Additionally, it's more secure as presigned URLs can expire or be limited in usage

Comment: Thank's @vuk-stanković but, how I can use the pre-signed URL on 1 POST request? If the user payload required a file attribute and, this file is larger than 6Mb, how I can use the pre-signed url before with this file > 6Mb?